# Кликом выбрали персонажа, а затем кликнули на что-то другое чтобы совершить действие, как отследить второй клик?

Tags: unity3d

Я пытаюсь сделать вот что. Допустим, у нас есть **человек**, мы кликаем на него, он "выбирается", а пока он выбран, если я нажму на **здание**, он туда пойдет. А если на нажму на **стул**, он на него пойдет и сядет и так далее.

Действий может быть много, от человека, кота, собаки и делать они могут разные вещи, нажимая на что-то второй раз

Я сделал так, чтобы можно было "взять" любой объект (с которым можно по игре взаимодействовать). Но я не понимаю, *как мне отследить этот ВТОРОЙ КЛИК?* Как мне после выбранного предмета отследить на что нажали вторым, чтобы отталкиваясь от выбора сделать определенное действие? И как мне расписать всю эту схему, если я сразу должен *управлять несколькими персонажами* (человек, кот, собака) и они все могут делать несколько действий??

Буду рад любой помощи! Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите как можно это реализовать:

1. Вам нужно создать скрипт, в котором будет это:

```
public string ID;
```

Данная строка будет отвечать за ID персонажа, которую мы будем передавать при втором клике. Этот скрипт переносите на персонажа и в поле, вписываете любой айди

2. Создаём прослойку, куда будем записывать промежуточные данные:

```
public string ID;
public GameObject object;
```

Т.е.: игрок кликает на объект, и в этом скрипте заполняются эти поля

3. Когда игрок будет кликать по дому, то эти данные будут браться из этой прослойки и с ними будут производиться какие-то действия, например:
   Если id == "dog", то object.goToHome

Думаю принцеп ясен

Comment: Спасибо за идею, я сейчас попробую и отпишусь

Comment: Если всё норм, то пометьте как решение

Comment: Я уже час сижу пишу код, у меня ничего не выходит. Только каша. Я понял вашу идею, но из всего этого кроме горы костылей ничего не выходит. Либо же я вашу идею  не до конца понял

Comment: Я надеюсь вы сможете мне привести конкретный пример, вроде:
1. Скрипт Ray, делает то-то то-то
2. Скрипт Data, сохраняет такие-то данные из Ray при клике

Иначе я не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Хорошо, завтра всё сделаю

Comment: спасибо! Жду с нетерпением

Comment: Надеюсь, вы все же ответите. Никак не могу найти решение данной проблемы

Comment: А что сложного? Если не знаешь основ c#, то лучше прекратить создание игр

Comment: я знаю основы как c#, так и самого Unity. А этот форум предназначен для помощи неопытным программистам и просто тем, кто не может в чем-то разобраться. 

Ваш "совет" совершенно не по теме.

Comment: Вот именно, это форум, а не фриланс

Comment: Я дал совет, как это можно реализовать. А если ты, не можешь создать класс, функцию и пердать в неё объекты, то значит ты смотрел Гошу дудя

Comment: Я могу реализовать все из вами перечисленного. И даже больше, чем вам могло бы показаться. 

И, если честно, не особо хочется общаться  с таким как вы человеком -  который с незнакомым ему человеком на "ты" разговаривает. 

Желаю вам успехов в программировании и не делать поспешных и неверных выводов.

Comment: Ахахаха, дак меня зачем нужно было тревожить?

Comment: я вас не тревожил. Вы сами себя потревожили.